# What's the fastest way to convert an interleaved NumPy integer array to complex64?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I have a stream of incoming data that has interleaved real and imaginary integers. Converting these to complex64 values is the slowest operation in my program. This is my current approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(1000000, dtype=np.int16)
b = np.complex64(a[::2]) + np.complex64(1j) * np.complex64(a[1::2])
```

Can I do better without making a C extension or using something like cython? If I can't do better, what's my easiest approach using a technology like one of these?

Comment: After playing around with a couple of things in straight numpy, I don't think you can improve on your current implementation (it's as fast compared to the small tweaks I made), although I haven't messed around with cython, etc.

Comment: You are not reading BRUKER MRI data, are you? If you are have a look at my sort of related problem: (see question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5422184/607562). Robert's answer below certainly rocks for your purposes.

Comment: @DrSAR: No, I'm working with radar data. Thanks for the pointer, though; it might be useful in some of my other operations.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
[~]
|1> import numpy as np

[~]
|2> a = np.zeros(1000000, dtype=np.int16)

[~]
|3> b = a.astype(np.float32).view(np.complex64)

[~]
|4> b.shape
(500000,)

[~]
|5> b.dtype
dtype('complex64')
```

Comment: blimey: I tried this on some of my data where I'm doing the same as OP Jim and can say that for an array of roughly 10 million numbers the above view technique takes 0.067s instead of 0.44s (6-7fold speedup); thumbs up for Robert Kern.

Comment: After 11 years, and working on radar data myself (interfacing with HDF5) this is simply the cat's pyjamas. 

Thank You!