# Is it possible to create a numpy.ndarray that holds complex integers?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create `numpy.ndarray` objects that hold complex integer values in them. NumPy does have complex support built-in, but for floating-point formats (`float` and `double`) only; I can create an `ndarray` with `dtype='cfloat'`, for example, but there is no analogous `dtype='cint16'`. I would like to be able to create arrays that hold complex values represented using either 8- or 16-bit integers.

I found [this mailing list post from 2007](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2007-October/029447.html) where someone inquired about such support. The only workaround they recommended involved defining a new `dtype` that holds pairs of integers. This seems to represent each array element as a tuple of two values, but it's not clear what other work would need to be done in order to make the resulting data type work seamlessly with arithmetic functions.

I also considered another approach based on [registration of user-defined types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html#user-defined-data-types) with NumPy. I don't have a problem with going to the C API to set this up if it will work well. However, the [documentation for the type descriptor strucure](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#PyArray_Descr.kind) seems to suggest that the type's `kind` field only supports signed/unsigned integer, floating-point, and complex floating-point numeric types. It's not clear that I would be able to get anywhere trying to define a complex integer type.

What are some recommendations for an approach that may work?

Whatever scheme I select, it must be amenable to wrapping of existing complex integer buffers without performing a copy. That is, I would like to be able to use `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData()` to expose the buffer to Python without having to make a copy of the buffer first. The buffer would be in interleaved real/imaginary format already, and would either be an array of `int8_t` or `int16_t`.

Comment: This is pretty - non-standard.  How do you define division for this type?  for example, what do you expect if you do `(2+1j)/(3+0j)`?  Do you expect it to give you a complex result or `(0+0j)`?

Comment: @mgilson: Understood. That particular case would have to be handled specially. I wouldn't say that it's nonstandard; complex integers are used very frequently in signal processing. Complex division is not a common operation in such contexts; I could live with that operation not being supported.

Comment: I am not comfortable with the C API, so I would subclass `ndarray`, force a dtype holding pairs of integers, and overload all the arithmetic operations for the new subclass.

Comment: Out of curiosity, when in signal processing are complex integers used?  I can't think of examples off the top of my head.

Comment: Which operations do you need?  I simple `ndarray` subclass might be good enough.

Comment: @acjohnson55: One application is in digital communications. Communications signals are often represented in what's called *complex baseband* format (this is also known as forming an *analytic signal*), which makes many common manipulations easier to model and implement.

Comment: @mgilson: Likely addition/subtraction and multiplication. I also just thought of another constraint that I'll edit into the post.

Comment: @JasonR -- I unfortunately don't have time to work on something of this magnitude right now, but it seems that you could accomplish something like this via a subclass using [view-casting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#view-casting).  You could add properties `imag` and `real` which would return views into the appropriate portions of the arrays.  And you could override `__mul__`,`__add__`,`__sub__` accordingly, but I don't know exactly how numpy-like you actually *need* this to be, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @JasonR: I'm familiar with complex baseband format, but I haven't seen a system that's restricted to complex integers, let alone where the abstraction would fail if you did floating point arithmetic.  But no biggie, I was just curious.

Comment: @acjohnson55: Floating-point format is the more typical case, but I will occasionally work with data that is stored as integers. While most processing is done in floating-point, for some common operations, I would like to be able to avoid a type conversion.

Comment: @EMS: I'm aware that most work is done in floating-point. However, I have a requirement to interface with libraries that use integer formats, so I would like to have the capability to, at a minimum, view and do some basic manipulations on complex integers without necessarily having to do the conversion to floating point. My desire is driven strictly by performance (i.e. speed).

Comment: @EMS: I fully understand the disadvantages of using integers for complex arithmetic. However, your argument isn't very constructive to this problem; suffice it to say that I have a *requirement* to sometimes interface with complex data that is formatted as integers.

Comment: Just to add to the discussion, I too have a requirement for complex integers. It's basically for modelling fixed point implementations of algorithms. This most certainly is _not_ rare. That said, in my case it can be worked around using floating point complex values with suitable rounding (since I'm only dealing with multiplication).

Comment: I have a requirement for complex integers too. My data size is around 1TBso the conversion time and memory usage is an issue.

Comment: All three links are broken. The first times out and the other two are *"404. Not Found"*.

Comment: Related: *[Is there a way to make a complex number in NumPy with the accuracy of the 'Decimal' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750012/)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also deal with lots of complex integer data, generally basebanded data.

I use

```
dtype = np.dtype([('re', np.int16), ('im', np.int16)])
```

It's not perfect, but it adequately describes the data. I use it for loading into memory without doubling the size of the data. It also has the advantage of being able to load and store transparently with HDF5.

```
DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
    H5T_STD_I16LE "re";
    H5T_STD_I16LE "im";
}
```

Using it is straightforward and is just different.

```
x = np.zeros((3,3),dtype)
x[0,0]['re'] = 1
x[0,0]['im'] = 2
x
>> array([[(1, 2), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
>>        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)],
>>        [(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]],
>>  dtype=[('re', '<i2'), ('im', '<i2')])
```

To do math with it, I convert to a native complex float type. The obvious approach doesn't work, but it's also not that hard.

```
y = x.astype(np.complex64) # doesn't work, only gets the real part
y = x['re'] + 1.j*x['im']  # works, but slow and big
y = x.view(np.int16).astype(np.float32).view(np.complex64)
y
>> array([[ 1.+2.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
>>        [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j],
>>        [ 0.+0.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j]], dtype=complex64)
```

This last conversion approach was inspired by [an answer to *What's the fastest way to convert an interleaved NumPy integer array to complex64?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658047/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-an-interleaved-numpy-integer-array-to-complex6/5658446#5658446)

Comment: I convert my array `f` (which looks like that: `array([(127, -128), (127, 127)], 
      dtype=[('I', 'i1'), ('Q', 'i1')])`) like that: `f_complex = [np.complex(*x) for x in f]`. Its still not a complex integer, but I think a more elegant solution to convert from int to complex float.

Comment: @StefanD. I expected your method to be slower, but I was shocked to measure >10000x slower on 1M points. It also only works for 1D (instead of any array), and `f_complex` is a list, not an array.

Comment: really creative. i wonder when you do this... is there a copy operation that happens when you use `y = x.view(np.int16).astype(np.float32).view(np.complex64)`, yes or no? if no. that's amazing IMO.

Comment: astype() does a type conversion (and copy), but view() does not. So that's one copy-and-convert operation.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using matrices of the form [[a,-b],[b,a]] as a stand-in for the complex numbers.

Ordinary multiplication and addition of matrices corresponds to addition an multiplication of complex numbers (this [subring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subring) of the collection of 2x2 matrices is isomorphic to the complex numbers).

I think Python can handle integer matrix algebra.

Comment: Thanks. It's possible that this could work *in principle*, but the main motivating factor was for efficiency, to allow creation of a view onto existing complex integer data. I think this method would require preprocessing the complex values into the matrix form that you suggested.

Comment: @JasonR The nice thing is that this would allow, for example, exact multiplication of $(23232+54546i)*(25436+123132132i)$ without any inexact arithmetic coming from the use of floats.

Answer (score -1):

Python, and hence NumPy, does support complex numbers. If you want complex integers, just use *np.round* or ignore the decimal part.

For example,

```
import numpy as np

# Create 100 complex numbers in a 1D array
a = 100*np.random.sample(100) + (100*np.random.sample(100)*1j)

# Reshape to a 2D array
np.round(a)
a.reshape(10, 10)

# Get the real and imaginary parts of a couple of x/y points as integers
print int(a[1:2].real)
print int(a[3:4].imag)
```

Comment: The OP wants complex *integers*.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say, use complex and treat as an integer.

Comment: This works for many applications. I suspect those down voting don't understand the problem.