# Is there a way to make a complex number in NumPy with the accuracy of a Decimal type?

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, precision, complex-numbers

I'm working in Python with NumPy arrays of complex numbers that extend well past the normal floating point limits of NumPy’s default *Complex* type (numbers greater than 10^500). I wanted to know if there was some way I could extend NumPy so that it will be able to handle complex numbers with this sort of magnitude. For example, is there a way to make a NumPy complex type that uses functionality from the Decimal module?

I know there are resources available such as [mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) that could probably do what I need. However, it is a requirement of my project that I use NumPy.

For anyone that's interested in why I need these enormous numbers, it's because I'm working on a [numerical relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_relativity) simulation of the early universe.

Comment: Did you try to create a numpy array of mpmath objects?

Comment: There's some info about [user-defined data types in NumPy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.beyond-basics.html#user-defined-data-types)

Comment: I hadn't thought about making an array of mpmath objects, I'l give it a try. Also that user-defined types article looks promising. Thank you both, I'll get back to you with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your platform, you may have support for complex192 and/or complex256. These are generally not available on Intel platforms under Windows, but they are on some others—if your code is running on [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29) or on a supercomputer cluster, it may support one of these types.  On Linux, you may even find them available or you could create your array using `dtype=object` and then use bigfloat or gmpy2.mpc.

1. complex256 numbers up to 10<sup>4932</sup> + 10<sup>4932</sup>j
2. complex192 ditto, but with less precision
3. I have even seen mention of NumPy and complex512...

Comment: Hmmm, my work is currently being split across both a windows machine and a Linux box...either I'll have to make both machines Linux, or find another solution. Thank you though, it gives me a nice avenue of investigation to look into.